# Order list beginning with null dates in Crystal Reports

Tags: date, null, crystal-reports, report

How can I order a list of date fields, beginning first with null dates. 
I created this formula:

> if isnull({BAQReportResult.JobHead.TravelerLastPrinted}) then 0 else 1

The format of date field {BAQReportResult.JobHead.TravelerLastPrinted} is datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Create a group with that Formula as the *Group By* field.

Suppress the Group Header and Footer. Place this group just outside the group you currently use to organize the dates so the nulls appear first.